# Targeting input number - step up

Tags: php, css, wordpress, input

using a woo-commerce WordPress theme, on the checkout page there's the option to increase quantity buy using a input, however its only visible on hover and I am trying to make that visible always, I assumed its hidden on normal state and visible when hovered but I cannot seem to find the class that controls that, is there a way to target this? [site link](http://edeals.nickritson.co.uk/cart/)

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone wanted the answer i found this to work.

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
    opacity:1;
}
```